# Extracting last UIImage frame from a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset

I'm using the next code to extract the last frame from a video:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailFromVideoAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    CMTime thumbnailTime = [asset duration];
    NSLog(@"value: %lld",thumbnailTime.value); //1650
    NSLog(@"timescale: %d",thumbnailTime.timescale); //1000
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];    
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:thumbnailTime actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return thumbnail;
}
```

The code and `CMTime` looks fine (it's a 1.65 seconds video) but I'm still getting back the first frame of the video (it's a mov file).
If I try the above code on longer videos I get a frame from the middle of the video or a frame that's close to the end but never the exact last frame.

Any idea what's the problem?

- I'm trying to avoid using something like ffmpeg.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should configure the `requestedTimeToleranceBefore` and `requestedTimeToleranceAfter` properties of the `AVAssetImageGenerator`. They default to `kCMTimePositiveInfinity` which means the closest key frame. If you set them both to `kCMTimeZero`, you will get the exact frame you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks Costique, Great answer. What still baffles me though is that the closest frame should be the last, defiantly not the first out of 1650 frames

Comment: @Segev I assume it works like this: apply the tolerance values to the requested time to get the time range, then use the first key frame in the time range (if any) or use the first frame in the time range otherwise. The rationale is that decoding key frames is fast, while decoding other frames requires decoding the last key frame plus _all_ the frames in between. With infinite tolerance the first key frame happens to be the very first video frame.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again!